Divergence defined w.r.t infinity? Or Divergence defined w.r.t there being a finite N s.t the iteration diverges at N? Mandelbrot Set.
This question is not about the concept of divergence in general. This question is about it only specific to the the map z^2 + c in the complex plane. This question creates two sets, defined differently, and asks if both the sets are they same set?
$$\text{the question of this post is (will be elaborated on): } \\ \mathbb{M}\_{\textsf{inf}} = \mathbb{M}\_{\text{computable}} \text{?}$$
The Question:
I am under the assumption of and I expect that there is a distinction between these two following possible definitions of the Mandelbrot set. Each of which would result in different sets, and different results.
The question is not

"which one is the correct one, or which is the canonical one, which one "is" the Mandelbrot Set?",

an opinion question like that is not good for stackexchange.
My question is:

"Do the following two definitions lead to different sets, that are distinct, and not the same as each other?"

Set $\mathbb{M}_{\textsf{inf}}$
"infinite operations version"
(more precise): For point $p=a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$. And for the mapping $f_n=(f_{n-1})^2 + (p)$ with $f_0 = 0$. Then p is a member of the set called $\mathbb{M}_{\text{inf}}$ under the condition that its magnitude after an infinite amount of iterations is still less than 2:
$$|\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n| < 2$$
(paraphrased): A point $p=a+bi$ is declared to have diverged only w.r.t its magnitude after taking infinite amount of iterations of $z^2+c$. If its magnitude after an infinite amount of iterations applied to it, is bigger than/eq to 2, then we declare it as diverged. You only have to iterate an infinite amount of times to know for sure (in the general case of all possible complex numbers which are uncountable). It is said to have diverged only with respect to an infinite amount of operations applied to it, in the limit, or otherwise. There may be points that do not diverge for any finite N, but do indeed diverge in the limit only at infinity.
Set $\mathbb{M}_{\text{computable}}$
"finite operations version"
This is an update to the below definition. There was some confusion in the comments on the idea of divergence being defined as "the ability to find any arbitrary big-N such that a_n surpasses big-N". This is not the notion of divergence here. We only need to check if its magnitude gets bigger than 2. Not if it also gets bigger than 9,99,999.. ect. And so, it may be prudent to extend the below definition, of $\mathbb{M}_{\text{computable}}$. In which "divergence" is declared w.r.t there being a minimum $f_M$, s.t M is the smallest natural in which |$f_M| >=2$ 
(more precise): For point $p=a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$. And for the mapping $f_n=(f_{n-1})^2 + (p)$ with $f_0 = 0$. Then p is a member of the set called $\mathbb{M}_{\text{computable}}$ under the condition that:
$\nexists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2 \leq |f_n|$
(paraphrased): A point $p=a+bi$ diverges iff, that after a finite amount of iterations of $z^2+c$, its magnitude is bigger than/eq to 2. You only have to iterate a finite amount of times. There will be some finite N at which it diverged
As a reminder, this isn't an opinion question, but a technical one. I am asking the question:
$$\text{THE QUESTION OF THIS POST IS: } \\ \mathbb{M}\_{\textsf{inf}} = \mathbb{M}\_{\text{computable}} \text{?}$$
Recap
To recap, the question is whether there is a nontrivial distinction between the set if you define with respect to its magnitude after only an infinite amount of operations have been applied to it. Or it with respect to the existence of some finite natural less than infinite in which it diverged at that finite natural. That, the set if you define it w.r.t an infinite amount of iterations applied to, whether that literally results in a different set.

You really should edit this down. Math.se expects fairly well focused questions.

I don't understand your question.  The Mandelbrot set is, by definition, the set of complex numbers $z_0$ which have bounded orbits with respect to the recurrence  $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + z_0$.  As a practical matter, it may be very difficult (or even impossible?) to know if any particular $z_0$ has a bounded orbit, so it is really only practical to approximate this set, but the underlying definition is not really up for debate...

@XanderHenderson Hi, thanks for commenting, I'd be glad to clear up confusion. Pretend this question is not about the mandelbrot set, so as to avoid preconceived notions. The question creates two Sets, M_inf, and M_computable. These two sets have membership defined differently. The question is, does M_inf = M_computable. Are they the same set? I expect that they are not.

@JonathanZ the extra parts of the post are for those there for context and background, for to answer a someone's question effectively, you need to know motivation and context. I anticipated that not everyone is like that. And so, I clearly marked with headings the part of the post which those who do not care for context or motivation. So that it is clearly, formatted to know where to read depending on the information you want. It may be typical that posts are smaller, and I agree it is rare, however, some may appreciate a longer post :)

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$, then there must exist some finite $N$ such that $n > N$ implies that $a_n > 2$.  This implies...?  (use the fact that determining the points of the Mandelbrot set is the same problem as determining the complement)

@JonathanZ hi, after reconsidering, I decided to edit the post down and cut it by 50% by entirely removing the personal thoughts section. I know people may only want the "meat" of the post. So thank you for letting me know, and I editted it after reconsidering

@XanderHenderson I do not see any necessary reason for why $|\lim_{x\to\infty} a_n| >=2$ implies the existence of a natural number n at which it diverged. Why? Analogy: The sum $n \to \infty$ of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ = 1. However, there does not exist any natural n in which that sum equaled one. It only reaches 1, in the limit of all infinite terms, at finite n, you get rationals like 0.984375 or 0.99609375. Only after an infinite amount of operations do you get 1. Thus, this provides a good analogy on why a limit equaling something does not imply there exists a natural s.t that limit is reached.

The meaning of the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ is that for any $M > 0$, there exists an $N > 0$ such that $n > N$ implies that $a_n > M$.   That is the definition of divergence to infinity.

@XanderHenderson the canonical definition of divergence is indeed w.r.t naturals. That you can find any arbitrary natural big-N, that a_n surpassed big-N. I know, however, my I do not believe it is relevant to my definitions above because of how I phrased it: I phrased it in terms of magnitude being larger/eq than 2. Ie, not in terms of "there being a big-N that you can find...", ect. It only uses the notion of magnitude being bigger/eq than 2. Nobody who computes the mandelbrot set checks if the magnitude gets larger than 1,99, 9999... They check if it gets larger than 2 which is sufficient

darn, -4 already in the first 20 mins. I spent an hour on this writing it for you guys. I'm afraid this question will get prematurely downvoted before it has the chance of being seen by someone who understands it and can answer it. So if you are such a person, please leave an answer and offer insight, otherwise, carry on. Let it be seen by others who may have an answer.

You could write this question in one paragraph - give the standard definition, give your alternative, ask if they're equal, and give at most two sentences on why you're curious and what you suspect to be the case. My guess is the down votes (mine included) are because of all the nattering about.

"I phrased it in terms of magnitude being larger/eq than 2"  Yes.  $2$ is a value that $M$ may take.  For any $M > 0$ (take $M=2$), there exists some $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $|a_n| > M$.  This is literally just the definition of the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$.

I didn't see the original even-longer version of this question, but I think throwing in this false sentence in the middle contributed to derailing the discussion: "There may be points that do not diverge for any finite N, but do indeed diverge in the limit only at infinity."

It seems like the primary question was basically about how limits of sequences work (that the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition turns it into facts about terms with finite indices), and after the initial edits I thought it was clear enough to answer (the other "questions" in my answer were just to give context that seemed relevant). Voting to reopen.

Questions
Define Mandelbrot sequences $f_{n\,;\,p}:=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if }n=0\\\left(f_{n-1}\right)^{2}+p & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.
Here is my interpretation of possible intended questions:

Is this true?: $p$ is in the Mandelbrot set $\Leftrightarrow\left(\nexists n\in\mathbb{N},\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|\ge2\right)$
Is this true?: $\forall p\in\mathbb{C},\left|{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\right|\le2\Leftrightarrow\left(\nexists n\in\mathbb{N},\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|>2\right)$
Is this true?: $\forall p\in\mathbb{C},\left({\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\text{ exists}\right)\Rightarrow\left(\left|{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\right|\le2\Leftrightarrow\left(\nexists n\in\mathbb{N},\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|>2\right)\right)$
Is this true?: $\forall p\in\mathbb{C},\left({\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\text{ exists}\right)\Rightarrow\left(\left|{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\right|<2\Leftrightarrow\left(\nexists n\in\mathbb{N},\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|\ge2\right)\right)$
Is this true?: $\forall p\in\mathbb{C},{\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}}\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|\le2\Leftrightarrow\left(\nexists n\in\mathbb{N},\left|f_{n\,;\,p}\right|>2\right)$

Answers
Question 1
Note that $f_{1\,;\,-2}=-2$, $f_{2\,;\,-2}=2$, and indeed $f_{n\,;\,-2}=2$ for $n\ge2$. (We say that $-2$ is in the Mandelbrot set because this sequence does not diverge - it just stays at $2$ after the first couple steps.)
Because of this counterexample, the answer to question 1 is no. $\left|{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,-2}\right|\nless2$ and $\left|f_{1\,;\,-2}\right|=\left|f_{17\,;\,-2}\right|=2$ and $p$ is in the Mandelbrot set because the sequence does not "diverge to infinity", for any definition of what that means.
Question 2
The answer to Question 2 is no, because the Mandelbrot set contains points $p$ where the corresponding sequence $f_{n\,;\,p}$ is eventually periodic, so that it loops around between multiple values. (See, for instance, the Wikipedia article on Misiurewicz points.)
For such a value of $p$, the limit doesn't exist (so we can't say "the limit exists and is bounded by $2$"), despite the fact that the sequence never escapes the disk of radius $2$.
Question 3
The answer to Question 3 is yes, because of how we define limits of sequences and the properties of the Mandelbrot set.
Proof:
We will work with the contrapositive.
Suppose that for a certain $m$, we had $\left|f_{m\,;\,p}\right|>2$. By the properties of the Mandelbrot set, the sequence $f_{n\,;\,p}$ would diverge to infinity, and we wouldn't have ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}$ existing to begin with.
Now suppose that $\left|{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}f_{n\,;\,p}\right|>2$. Then there exists a limit $L$ with $|L|>2$ such that for all error tolerances $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow\left|f_{n\,;\,p}-L\right|<\varepsilon$. But then by choosing $\varepsilon=|L|-2$, and applying a version of the triangle inequality, we would have an $m$ such that $\left|f_{m\,;\,p}\right|>2$.
Question 4
I honestly do not know the answer to Question 4, because I don't know off the top of my head if the Mandelbrot set has points $p$ where the sequence $f_{n\,;\,p}$ approaches the circle of radius $2$ from the inside. I don't think this was the main focus of the question, though.
Question 5
This, using the limit superior, is the version of Question 3 that doesn't need to assume the limit exists.
The answer is still yes, and the proof is very similar to that for Question 3.


There may be points that do not diverge for any finite $N$, but do indeed diverge in the limit only at infinity.

I note that this isn't really true: all definitions of getting past absolute value $2$ in the limit require getting past $2$ at some finite stage.
